# how to cast or convert numeric/varchar to date data type field in sql and use in update statement?

Tags: sql-server

Good day!

I have 2 questions how to update a date data type column field using varchar and numeric column field

1.)`mydate` varchar(8)--> `varchar` column field

```
SELECT mydate from mytable
```

> Result: 20141120

my question is how can I update my date column field using my varchar column field using cast or convert

```
update table2
set date = (select mydate from mytable)
```

which I get an error!!! and I'm stuck.

2.)`mydate` numeric(8) --> `numeric column` field

```
SELECT mydate from mytable
```

> Result:
>
> 20101015
>
> 20140910

etc.......

```
update table2
set date = (select mydate from mytable a, mytable2 b
where a.id=b.id)
```

my question is how can I update my date column field using my numeric column field using cast or convert

I used different CAST and CONVERT but still I'm getting error!

What is the correct syntax for this?

Thank your for your help!

Comment: Post your work using Cast and convert in the question.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a string to a date field you will need to use the CONVERT function:

```
CONVERT(datetime, mydate, 101)
```

This is expecting a string field, so if your mydate field is really a numeric field then you will need to CAST that to a string, so the CONVERT command will then look like:

```
CONVERT(datetime, CAST(mydate as VarChar), 101)
```

The third parameter of the function is determined by the format of the date in the previous parameter, you can find the full list on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the feedback I will check and let you know.